# Double suffixes?

Tags: word-formation

Is there any specific rule which forbids the same **suffix applied twice in a row**?

Context: I've randomly tried to imagine what programming variables would be called in Esperanto and realized that "workshopFactory" is technically *laborejejo*, since it's a place where places for working reside.

So I tried creating more -- I've thought that you could jokingly say that you're *laboremema*, meaning you're eager to be eager to get working on something, in a sense that you're lazy. In a similar way you can go overboard with -aĉ-, like *hundaĉaĉo*.

I have a feeling that -ar- (along with my original -ej-) might be the easiest to imagine, like a group of forests in close proximity could be *arbararo*, but they still keep looking fabricated to me.

I couldn't come up with something more concrete and common, so I'm also wondering: are there **common words** which use this pattern?

Comment: Not sure if this exactly counts for what you want, because its not consecutive, but the word _rid·et·ul·et·o_ pops in my head to describe *:)*. Leaving out one of the *et*s does not suffice, because then it is either not small, or not smiling, but laughing.

Comment: Mi ne certas ke "ejo" estas bona traduko for "factory".

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern Ĝi havas sencon en programa konteksto.

Comment: Eble "kreilo"? ("Factory" en la programada senco ne vere estas loko, laŭ mia kompreno.)

Comment: (**laborejaro** would do here)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no rule that forbids the combination of affixes in Esperanto, **as long as the resulting words have a recognizable sense**.*

There is, however, outside joking/mocking language (IIRC Karol Pič named Richard Schulz "tradukantanto", in order to mock his overly complicated style), no example known to me where the same affix would appear twice and have a clear sense.

In any case you should know that "stacking" affixes does not reinforce their meaning, so your *hundaĉaĉo wouldn't do the trick.

*There may be some minor exceptions, which however are not worth consideration here.

TL;DR: Nothing forbids you to do so, but there are hardly any use cases.

Comment: A friend just reminded me that I once used the word _denaskululoj_ in order to name the people on the mailing list for parents of Esperanto native speakers (_denaskuloj_). This may be an example of a sensible use.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't know any common words doing this (Mi mem estas komencanto.), I don't see any reason not to do it, especially in humorous or sarcastic speech/writing.

In more serious context, especially in clean-code programming where you want your names to be as clear and understandable as possible, splitting the words may be more appropriate: "laboreja ejo", "lobareme ema", "vere aĉa hundaĉo". (To convert these to variable names, use `CamelCase` or `snake_case` or other variants to indicate word boundaries following the applicable coding standard for the programming language or specific project/team.)